# Sequential List Implementation

Tags: delphi

I was trying to implement a sequential linked list class similar to Delphi's TList class. Here instead of allowing the user to set the count property, the class will automatically increments/decrements the count property. So, instead of initializing the array inside the setcount procedure, the class will initialize the array element just before adding the object referenceto the array. Here is the code:

```
    PObjectarray = ^TObjectarray;
    TObjectarray = array of TObject;
    TSequentialList = class
    private
      FObjects: PObjectarray;
      FCapacity: Integer;
      FCount: Integer;
    protected
      procedure GrowList;virtual;
      procedure SetCapacity(aValue: Integer);
    public
      constructor Create(aCapacity: Integer); overload;
      Constructor Create;overload;
      procedure Add(aObject:TObject);
      procedure Delete(aIndex:Integer);
      destructor Destroy;override;    
   End;
```

Implementation: -

```
    procedure TSequentialList.Add(aObject: TObject);
    begin
      if FCount=FCapacity then
        GrowList;
      FillChar(FObjects^[FCount],sizeof(TObject),0);//Initialize the FCount's member space
      FObjects^[FCount]:=aObject;
      Inc(FCount);
    end;

    constructor TSequentialList.Create(aCapacity: Integer);
    begin
      FCapacity := 0;
      FCount := 0;
      SetCapacity(aCapacity);
    end;

    constructor TSequentialList.Create;
    begin
      FCapacity := 0;
      FCount := 0;
    end;

    procedure TSequentialList.Delete(aIndex: Integer);
    var tmpObj:TObject;
    i:Integer;
    begin
     if (aIndex>=FCount) or (aIndex<0) then raise ELinkedListException.Create('Invalid Index in Delete..!');
     tmpObj:=FObjects^[aIndex];
     tmpObj.Free;

     System.Move(FObjects^[aIndex+1],FObjects^[aIndex],(FCount-aIndex)* SizeOf(TObject));
     Dec(FCount);
    end;

    destructor TSequentialList.Destroy;
    begin
      SetCapacity(0);
      inherited;
    end;

    procedure TSequentialList.GrowList;
    var delta:Integer;
    begin
      if FCapacity>64 then
        delta:=FCapacity div 64
      else if FCapacity>16  then
           delta:=8
      else delta:=4;
      SetCapacity(FCapacity+delta);
    end;

    procedure TSequentialList.SetCapacity(aValue: Integer);
    var i:Integer;
    begin
      if FCapacity <> aValue then begin
         if aValue<FCount then begin
            for i := FCount-1 downto  aValue do
               Delete(i);
         end;
         ReallocMem(FObjects, aValue*sizeof(TObject));
         FCapacity := aValue;
      end;
    end;
```

Usage: //doesn't work

```
    procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var lst:TSequentialList;
    obj:TIntObj;
    begin
      lst:=TSequentialList.Create(4);
      obj:=TIntObj.Create(10);
      lst.Add(obj);
      lst.Add(TIntObj.Create(20));
      lst.Free;
    end;
```

The system hangs after exiting the above method. Please guide me what is wrong with the program.

Comment: Don't mix dynamic arrays and pointer-based methods

Answer (score 1):

I would first of all say that this is not a linked list. That's a very different structure. What's more, rather than reimplementing `TObjectList`, you should simply use the built-in class that is supplied with Delphi.

---

The fundamental problem with your code is that you are using dynamic arrays incorrectly. You must not use raw allocation functions like `ReallocMem`. Functions like `GetMem`, `ReallocMem` etc. are for use with raw pointers. The lifetime of dynamic arrays is managed by the compiler/runtime library.

To allocate dynamic arrays you must use `SetLength`.

The other significant error is that the call to `System.Move` moves the wrong number of elements.

The code below is a simplified and corrected variant of your code.

```
type
  TMyObjectList = class
  private
    FObjects: array of TObject;
    FCount: Integer;
  protected
    procedure GrowList;
    procedure SetCapacity(aValue: Integer);
  public
    constructor Create(aCapacity: Integer); overload;
    constructor Create; overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Add(aObject: TObject);
    procedure Delete(aIndex: Integer);
  end;

constructor TMyObjectList.Create(aCapacity: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetCapacity(aCapacity);
end;

constructor TMyObjectList.Create;
begin
  Create(0);
end;

destructor TMyObjectList.Destroy;
begin
  SetCapacity(0);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyObjectList.Add(aObject: TObject);
begin
  if FCount = Length(FObjects) then
    GrowList;
  FObjects[FCount] := aObject;
  Inc(FCount);
end;

procedure TMyObjectList.Delete(aIndex: Integer);
begin
  if (aIndex >= FCount) or (aIndex < 0) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid Index in Delete..!');

  FObjects[aIndex].Free;
  System.Move(FObjects[aIndex+1], FObjects[aIndex], 
    (FCount-aIndex-1)*SizeOf(TObject));
  Dec(FCount);
end;

procedure TMyObjectList.GrowList;
var
  delta: Integer;
begin
  if Length(FObjects) > 64 then
    delta := Length(FObjects) div 64
  else if Length(FObjects) > 16 then
    delta := 8
  else
    delta := 4;
  SetCapacity(Length(FObjects) + delta);
end;

procedure TMyObjectList.SetCapacity(aValue: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Length(FObjects) <> aValue then
  begin
    for i := aValue to FCount-1 do
      FObjects[i].Free;
    SetLength(FObjects, aValue);
  end;
end;
```

But I urge you to use the built-in RTL classes that are known to work. For example, if you are using a modern version of Delphi you can use one of the generic containers from `System.Generics.Collections`. In your case `TObjectList<T>` appears to be what you need. In older Delphi versions you would use `TObjectList` from the `Contnrs` unit.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the delete-method is definetly wrong:

```
 for i := FCount-1 downto  aValue do
           Delete(i);
```

call `Delete(aValue)` instead.

But nonetheless, your code does not implement a linked list. It looks very much as if you are trying to implement TObjectList.

Comment: No, that code is actually correct. It's in `SetCapacity`.

Comment: Oops, of course David. The fraud code was it SetCapacity.

Comment: My main point is that your answer is wrong. The code in SetCapacity in the question is correct.

Comment: Oh god, I'm getting old. Time to switch to garden work.